# How to organize SenTestSuite hierarchy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit

I need to have custom SenTestSuite hierarchy to organize leveled setUp/tearDown, i.e. at the root level I setup some staff which is common to all my tests and should be set up only once, then I may have groups of test cases which, in turn, require some setup (common to a group) which again needs to be executed once for a group, and so on.

How to organize such hierarchy? (where to subclass? where to initialize?)

Also, I need to be able to run all my tests (i.e. root suite with all its children) from command-line and selectively from Xcode, within a build phase (selected tests should be run in their suite hierarchy, so all the necessary setup executed). Is it possible?

Thanks.